# ArrayList of Fragment of ViewPager2 is null after I switched another fragment from NavigationView. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am making an Android project. I created a `RecyclerView` in `ViewPager2` as follows:

1. [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XY68.jpg)
2. [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9HSL.jpg)

I switched to `Gallery` or `Slideshow`. Then, I returned back to `Home` and clicked the `Clear Box` button. As soon as I clicked the button, the app crashed. The error was a `nullPointerException`.

My Adapter code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

My fragment code:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
    Button button;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    BoxAdapter adapter;
    private List<Box> boxList;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    int t;

    public OneFragment(int k) {
        t = k;
        Log.d("QQQ", "OneFragment constructor called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.click);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        boxList = new ArrayList<>();
       
        for(int i=0; i<t; i++) {
            boxList.add(new Box(i+1, Mode.NOTCHECKED));
        }
        adapter = new BoxAdapter(getActivity(), boxList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked me. T= "+t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void clearBox() {
        boxList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getBoxSize() {
        if(boxList == null) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return boxList.size();
        }
    }
}
```

My home fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    private Button button;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private OneFragment oneFragment;
    private TwoFragment twoFragment;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();   
        button = binding.clearbox;
        viewPager2 = binding.viewpager;

        int q;
        q = new Random().nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;
       
        oneFragment = new OneFragment(q);
        twoFragment = new TwoFragment();

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

        myAdapter.addFragment(oneFragment);
        myAdapter.addFragment(twoFragment);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);      

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                oneFragment.clearBox();  // app crashed on this line. Null pointer after returned from Gallery or Slideshow. Why?                
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

The error that I got:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.navbartest2, PID: 18771
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.navbartest2.adapter.BoxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.navbartest2.fragment.OneFragment.clearBox(OneFragment.java:82)
        at com.example.navbartest2.ui.home.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:72)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the error logs for more clarification

Comment: Full project is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M0BwonXUjY8IrSAtQWS6SlBquMB28W75/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you can upload your project on github and share link as then you can check the changes from repository easily

Answer (score 0):

As I try to solve that which I understand your object is not being called when you just calling constructor of the oneFragment. So I suggest you to try below code into the constructor of oneFragment.
try to add this code on constructor and can check.
also add try catch to prevent unwanted condition of null pointer or etc. on clearBox method befor calling it.

`public OneFragment(int k) { boxList = new ArrayList<>(); for(int i=0; i<t; i++) {boxList.add(new Box(i+1, Mode.NOTCHECKED));} }`

Comment: When I returned from Slideshow or Gallery, adapter of OneFragment and recyclerView of OneFragment are null.

Comment: Full project is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M0BwonXUjY8IrSAtQWS6SlBquMB28W75/view?usp=sharing